# How to read from file and store multiple integers on one line into arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

Having an issue when ran I get Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException.
I tried to debug and noticed that it will read from the file and store 10,10,1 but then it stops..

Example File:

```
testsom 10 testson 10
bgn 1 2
```

I think it's because of the white space but i'm not entirely sure.

```
public void readInput(String filename) throws IOException 
{

        File file = new File(filename);

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

        ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int num = 0;
        while(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            scan.next();

            num = scan.nextInt();
            values.add(num);
           // scan.nextInt();
            
        }
}
```

Comment: I guess this has nothing to do with files, or reading from files, but rather about Strings and parsing them. Please edit your question to show sample Strings (your file lines) and expected results, and remove everything related to files (including in the title), which your code is reading OK. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I removed the “file-io” tag accordingly.

Comment: Your input file doesn't really have a clear organization to it's structure. It has multiple values on the first line and white space breaking up your values in the second line. You probably want to edit your input to make it consistent for parsing/line-reading.

Comment: I need to account for variance

Comment: If this is solved, and if the answer might benefit future readers, could you add a self-answer below, in the answer space? Thanks!